# How to get the content of "Google Dictionary" by python script

Tags: python, web-services, web-applications

Thank to [the script](http://everydayscripting.blogspot.com/2009/10/python-fixes-to-google-login-script.html), I've logged in google successfully.
But I replaced the value of "gv_home_page_url" with http:// www.google.com.tw/dictionary/wordlist?hl=zh-TW, the error occured.

The message is **"
urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 500: Internal Server Error"**

Any idea will be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Nothing to do on your side beside using http://www.google.com/dictionary/wordlist?hl=zh-TW and not .com.tw
Same error 500, when opening the page in a browser.

Comment: Did you mean even if you open with browser, same error occured?
It works for me, did you log in google?

Answer (score 1):

That's not a valid URL. If you try to enter it in your bar, you'll get redirected to Google search results. Using urllib2, you'll get an error.

See here for another way to get data from Google Dictionary:

http://googlesystem.blogspot.com/2009/12/on-googles-unofficial-dictionary-api.html

Comment: Thanks, is there also API for starred wordlist?

Comment: @user313439: I'm not sure what that is.

Answer (score 0):

Does Google require an SSL url? You're using "http://" but the example script uses "https://"